# Play rock, scissor and paper. If you win by rock, you get 2 points

Tags: probability, expected-value, game-theory

Play rock, scissor and paper. If you win by rock, you get 2 points, if you win by paper or scissor, you get one point. If you are tie, you get zero point. Provide a strategy that you can get more points than your rival.

---

First of all, what are the probabilities like in this game?

Because you have $1/3$ chance to win on every move, but you also have $1/3$ chance of selecting a move(R, S, or P). Should we account for that in probability or not?

You cannot always pick rock because your opponent knows that you have an incentive to do that and thus he would choose paper and beat you.

Comment: Well the always choosing rock thing is kind of paradoxical (I've heard of this paradox before). It's like if you are a soccer player and you want to either shoot the ball left or right. If you always go left, the goalie will go left. Similarly for right.

Comment: "Provide a strategy that you can get more points than your rival" seems a bit optimistic.  (A) Your opponent could follow the same strategy. (B) If your strategy is deterministic then your opponent can always beat it, while if it involves some randomness then you may be unlucky

Comment: @Henry- surely even if your strat involved randomness, if opponent uses same strat as you then you won’t win in the long run.

Comment: Please clarify: Does the rival get points in the same way (2/1/1)? The question only says that "you" get points that way.

Comment: "a strategy that you can get more points than your rival" is also ambiguous. Is this strategy supposed to deterministically ensure our point total is higher? Or are we going for a higher expected value than our opponent? Or are we trying to ensure we have a >50% probability of coming out with more points than the opponent? Or are we just going for the extremely weak property where we *literally can* get more points, as in, there is a possible outcome where we get more points? How many rounds are we playing, anyway?

Comment: suitable Markov chain $+$ optional stopping theorem $=$ no winning (or losing) strategy, unless one can predict opponent moves.

Comment: Any strategy "can" get you more points than some hypothetical person using an unknown strategy themselves. If we assume that's "is likely to" instead of "can", there is no strategy is likely to get you more points than some not-yet-known strategy. This may be the answer you're looking for or it might be the case that there's some assumption here that you, or the person who asked you this question, forgot to include.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps we should calculate the Nash equilibrium for this game. The payoff matrix is as below. Rows/columns are indexed as R, P, S and the payoffs in the matrix are for the player whose options are on the left, call it player 1.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 & 2 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
-2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let the player 1 play rock, paper or scissors with probabilities $p_1, p_2$ and $1-p_1-p_2$ respectively. Similarly define $q_1, q_2$ for player 2. Now we can write the expected value for the payoff of player 1 when playing R, P, S are

$$
\begin{aligned}
&E_R = p_1(-q_2 + 2(1-q_1-q_2)) \\
&E_P = p_2(q_1 - (1-q_1-q_2)) \\
&E_S = (1-p_1-p_2)(-2q_1+q_2)
\end{aligned}$$

Now, we know that neither player will have the upperhand, so all these expected values should be equal to $0$.
The bottom two say that we should have $q_1 = \frac{1}{4}, q_2=\frac{1}{2}$, (it will be similarly for $p$'s by symmetry). So you play paper with probability half and the others with one fourth. But I don't know why the first equation doesn't work. Making some of the probabilities zero doesn't work either, or I can't see it.

**EDIT:** Oh, but yes the first equation does also give $\frac{1}{2}+2(1-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{2}) = 0$. Well anyway, I also did this simulation and it backs up that indeed $[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4}]$ is correct.

```
def getRand(ps):
    u = random()
    v = 0
    ret = -1
    while v<u and ret<len(ps):
        ret += 1
        v += ps[ret]
    return ret
        
#0=R, 1=P, 2=S
def simuGame(ps, pick1=None):
    v1 = pick1 if pick1!=None else getRand(ps)
    v2 = getRand(ps)
    if v1==v2: return 0
    if v1==0 and v2==2:
        return 2
    if v1==0 and v2==1:
        return -1
    if v1==1 and v2==0:
        return 1
    if v1==1 and v2==2:
        return -1
    if v1==2 and v2==0:
        return -2
    if v1==2 and v2==1:
        return 1
        
simuN = 10000
ptsRPS = [0]*3
pickProbs = [0.25, 0.5, 0.25]
for i in range(simuN):
    for pick1 in range(3):
        ptsRPS[pick1] += simuGame(pickProbs, 0)
    
print ([float(x/simuN) for x in ptsRPS])
```

Comment: Interesting how, even though the game intuitively sounds like rock gives an advantage and scissors a disadvantage, the equilibrium strategy plays both with the same low probability.

Comment: @Troposphere Actually, I'm not entirely sure about the correctness since that one equation doesn't seem to agree with it. If someone could assure the calculations?

Comment: If $q_1=\frac14$ and $q_2=\frac12$ and $1-q_1-q_2=\frac14$ then $-q_2+2(1-q_1-q_2)=-\frac12+2\times \frac14=0$ and so $E_R=p_1(1-q_2+2(1-q_1-q_2)) =0$ and the first equation does work

Comment: The structure of the equilibrium becomes more visible with more choices. Suppose  here are $2n+1$ possible plays numbered $0$ through $2n$, and play $i+1$ wins one over $i$ for $0\le i<2n$, and $0$ wins two over $2n$. (If the two player's choices are not neighbors (cyclically), the game is a draw). Then the equilibrium strategy is to play each of the _even-numbered_ plays with probability $\frac{1}{3n+1}$ and each of the _odd-numbered_ plays with probability $\frac{2}{3n+1}$.

Comment: On the other hand, if there are an _even_ number ($\ge 4$) of possible plays, then the equilibrium is underdetermined -- but one particular equilibrium is that both players chose uniformly between the _even_ plays only. Then the outcome is always a draw, but no player has any incentive to ever consider an odd play.

Answer (score 6):

This is impossible. Suppose such a strategy existed; one where you would end up with more points than your opponent. Then your opponent can use the exact same strategy and beat you, because neither player has an advantage (like the first player (White) in chess is supposed to have a slight edge in general). Therefore your opponent can get more points than you, contradicting you having got more points than them. Therefore our assumption that such a strategy exists is wrong: no such strategy exists.

In order for us to have a winning strategy, we would need to know in advance any strategies our opponent is likely to use. Kind of like, you can't reliably win in poker in the long run, unless you know/figure out the tendencies of opponents. Sure you can play GTO (game theory optimal), but this doesn't guarantee you winning, because your opponent might also be playing GTO, in which case both you and opponent's EV's will be $0$...

Comment: With the game theory optimal strategy here, your expected gain is $0$ no matter how your opponent plays, but it is unlikely after a large number of games that you will be tied

Comment: Yeah, but what I meant is the EV will be $0$. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.